# How do you form this perfect continuous sentence in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, perfect-continuous

> ''They have been giving us water for 3 days.''

What is the passive of the above sentence?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Could it also be **We have been given water, by them,  for three days**?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Nothing wrong with the grammar of your sentences, but they do not strictly answer the question. The OP's sentence was in the continuous. So you need *We have been being given water for 3 days*.

Answer (score 1):

I read about this many, many years ago but cannot cite the source.  That source cited the example:

- **Active**: *They have been building that house for the past five years (and they still haven’t finished).*

When converted to Passive, according to the standard rules of English grammar, you must add another BE form giving:

- **Passive**: *That house has been being built for the past five years (and is still not finished).*

Clearly even native English speakers are uncomfortable with the form “has been being built” so will use the Active voice rather than the Passive in such circumstances.

Nevertheless it is a perfectly proper formulation. To answer your question “Water has been being given to us for the past three days”.  Correct but very odd.

Comment: Perfectly correct, Patrick, but it's usual to add an authoritative source showing 'the standard rule of English grammar' involved. // Adding the agent ('Water has been being given to us by them for the past three days') is equally grammatical but even more unidiomatic.

Comment: Noted.  Thank you.